# Need a suggestion on my table schema design for a simple case where I have a field could have two kind of types

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

(I am using TypeOrm with PostgreSql in my Node.js (NestJs) project).

I need to have simple relationships of my entity, I illustrate the idea using typescript code:

```
interface School {
   id: string,
   junior?: Local | International
   high?: Local | International
}

interface Local {
   type: 'local'
}


interface International {
   type: 'international',
   language: string[], //e.g. ['en', 'fr']
   foreignTeacherNr: number
}
```

So, A `School` could be a junior school or high school or both or none.

For each school the type could be `local` school or `international` one.

There can only be these two types of schools. For international school, there will be more information need to be stored e.g. language, foreign teacher number.

I need to translate them to DB tables & entities. I wonder the best approach to design the table schemas.

I am thiking two options:

Option 1:

- Creating a `School` entity/table, which has a column/field `shchool_type`
- Creating a `school_type` table which has only `id` & `name` columns
- Creating a `international_school` & having a foreign key pointing to `school_type`

Option 2:

- Creating a `School` entity/table, which has a column/field `shchool_type`
- Creating a `school_type` table which has all columns: `id`, `name`, `language`, `foreign_teacher_nr`. And for `name`=`local` using `null` values for `language` and `foreign_teacher_nr`

Which option do you think better? Any other option you would suggest considering there are only two types of schools?

Answer (score 0):

Which approach you will go depends greatly on context in which the model will be used and on your needs.

I would start with one entity School, with columns: id,name,address (or split in two columns - city and street), language, type,…

You need teacher entity, which holds data - id, name, subject(s), other data…

Then, if you need relation with school-teacher, most probably manyToMany relation and third table SchoolTeacher to hold the data, with columns - schoolId, teacherId

Again, it can be modeled in different ways, depending what you decide as good enough approach and depending on your knowledge.